# Slow Loading / Updating on Controls using Entity Framework - Am I doing it wrong?

Tags: c#, vb.net, entity-framework, data-binding, ado.net

I'm very new to Entity Framework and, so, as a test, I simply created a SQL Server Database-First EF6 Winforms project (in Visual Studio 2013) and didn't change anything in the Visual Studio created code such as Lazy / Optimistic loading, etc.

Now, I get all my data for this project from a somewhat large table with, for example, data of the form of:

```
Var1  | Start_Date |  End_Date  |  .... Other Columns ....
---------------------------------------------------------
Val1  | 1/1/2014   |  1/2/2014  |  ...
Val1  | 1/2/2014   |  1/3/2014  |  ...
Val1  | 1/5/2014   |  1/6/2014  |  ...
Val1  | 1/7/2014   |  1/8/2014  |  ...
Val1  | 1/9/2014   |  1/10/2014 |  ...
    ....
Val2  | 1/1/2014   |  1/2/2014  |  ...
Val2  | 3/2/2014   |  3/3/2014  |  ...
    ....
```

So, what I wanted to have was 3 `ComboBoxes` on my form - One where the user would select `Val1` and the other 2 that are updated on `ComboBox1.Change` to show all the unique start and end dates available for that specific value of `Val1`.

The code I used for doing this is:

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Using ctx As New MyEntities
            Dim Var1Query = (From rw In ctx.MyTable
                             Order By rw.Val1
                             Select rw.Val1).Distinct.ToList

            cboVal1.DataSource = Var1Query 
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub cboVal1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboVal1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Using ctx As New MyEntities
         ' Figured to get both dates at once rather than 2 trips to the DB
         Dim Dates = (From rw In ctx.MyTable
                      Where rw.Val1= cboVal1.Text
                      Select New With
                      {
                        .Start_Date = rw.Start_Date,
                        .End_Date = rw.End_Date
                      }).ToList


         Dim Start_Dates As List(Of Date)
         Start_Dates = (From el In Dates
                        Select el.Start_Date).Distinct.ToList

         Dim End_Dates As List(Of Date) = 
         End_Dates = (From el In Dates
                      Select el.End_Date).Distinct.ToList

         cboStartDates.DataSource = Start_Dates
         cboEndDates.DataSource = End_Dates
     End Using
End Sub
```

Now, this works, but it's VERY slow and even hangs up the UI the moment the user selects a new `Val1` while it's querying for the new Start / End Dates.

I'm **sure** this isn't the right way and just want to know what the right way to do something like this would be.

**Current Environment:**

- Visual Studio 2013
- Entity FrameWork 6
- SQL Server 2008

Also, even though the source code provided is in VB, I'm equally comfortable with VB / C# solutions.

Thanks!!!

Comment: How large is the record set your working with?

Comment: @Justin, truly, not THAT big... A table with, say, 1 million rows and 10 columns....

Comment: Have you looked at SQL Profiler to see the query being generated?  Using the query they have, try using it with the `Display Estimated Execution Plan` in SSMS.  I'm guessing your real issues aren't EF, but that you are doing distinct on 1 million records.  This will cause a table scan and sorts on top of that.  Splitting the distinct values into another table maybe worthwhile.

Comment: @Justin, so, in essence, I did the EF part correctly?? If that is the case, I'll work on the SQL Server part for sure, but I was afraid I was just doing that part wrong and so didn't want to go further to try and fix / speed up a bad way of doing things.... My main aim here is to learn how to do things as intelligently / efficiently as possible with EF, hence the bounty... Then I figured I can work on the deeper issues.... Make sense??

Comment: I don't believe that the problem here would be exactly those distincts (or EF), even tho they hurt a bit. But downloading 1Million rows into memory.. Well that would hurt I guess. And we don't exactly know how well is that table indexed, etc...

Comment: What indexes exist in the target table? Executing a _select distinct startdate, enddate_ directly on SSMS has a good performance?

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro I don't know how much an index would really help.  To get all the `Distinct` values, you would have to look at every row.  Depending on the server hardware, it could take a little.  If indeed 1 Million records were created in memory, I would suggest splitting the tables.

Comment: As I pointed out in the question, though, I'm not creating a 1-million row list in memory... MOST of the rows are repeated - I'm creating, maybe, a 200 row list in memory and, I **believe** the way I wrote the linq, the distinct operation happens on the SQL Server side, not in my code, no??

Comment: It does happen in memory, and you do get 1M records into memory. After you do ToList(), you execute the query as Justin said before. E: Well, after the "where". It might not be 1M records, indeed, my bad

Comment: Thank you, @BrunoMonteiro... I didn't realize the `.Distinct` happened on my side.. I thought all happened on the DB side until I called the `ToList()` operation... Sorry for my lack in understanding....

Comment: No, no. You are right. It "all" happens on the Database until you do "ToList". I meant the 2nd query where you get both dates (which has no distincts), and AFTER has 2 distincts using everything in memory. I'm not saying you were wrong.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the clarification!!!! - I'll also play with the idea of maybe then hitting the DB twice, then, once for each of the 2 dates... Maybe that would prove more efficient too... Thank you for your help / insights, @BrunoMonteiro!!!!

Comment: The problem could lie in the winform's combobox, not in EF, assigning DataSource to huge records could freeze the UI, if that happens you need something like autocomplete

Comment: @YuliamChandra, by the time I bind it, the list is "fairly small", though.... Like 200-500 items max....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you have provided, I don't see anything wrong with your EF code.  Most now use the LINQ extension methods to accomplish what they need as it isn't as verbose as the straight LINQ.  I do believe they end up getting translated to the extension methods anyway.

#### LINQ:

`From record in dbContext.MyTable Select new {record.Start_Date};`

#### LINQ Extensions:

`dbContext.MyTable.Select(x => new {x.Start_Date});`

See how they are shorter and convey the same meaning?

You selecting the fields you are interested in also is a very good habit.  It will reduce the size of the query sent to the server and will also reduce the result returned by the server.

You are using the `using` statement so the context is disposed of, not leaving a connection open when not being used.  This is good, but with a winform app, it is debatable if the context should live for the life of the form being displayed.

---

#### EF in general

When you create your criteria using LINQ, that is actually a SQL statement being built and nothing has executed yet.  Before you can access the results of the query, you will need to "materialize" the results.  To do this you just need access an element from the query to send it to the server for the results.  You **are** doing this by using `ToList`.  You should always do this unless you are still conditionally building the query up.

Something very important is that Lazy-loading, in most cases, isn't a good thing.  It is very convenient but it can create n+1 conditions and you will take a hit to performance since every child collection item you are accessing on the parent will generate a query to get it.  This is where using a tool like `AutoMapper` or using the `Include` statement will get everything from the server in one go.

For example: `var orderWithDetails = db.Orders.Include(order => order.LineItems).FirstOrDefault(order => order.Id == 4);` will generate a SQL statement that will select the order with an `id = 4` and generate additional sql to select all the `LineItem` records associated with it.  If you didn't do this and had lazy loading enabled, this could generate multiple child queries hurting performance.

It is important to remember that ORM's just make accessing the data easier for us and don't remove the need for performance testing other components of the system.

---

### EDIT:

I feel this is something that should be included and @BrunoMonteiro did point it out.  When you are selecting your distinct dates, you are doing it off a materialized query, `Dates`.  So all of that would occur on the client and not in SQL Server.  Depending on how many records are associated with the recordset returned from your `Where` clause, it could be an issue.

You should see how many are being returned and the potential max returned.  If it seems excessive, I would recommend you generate separate statements for them and send them to the SQL Server to handle.  In general, the client processes equally or better than the server on a reduced result set.

Comment: Thanks SO MUCH, @Justin - As for your statements... I always jump around between the extension methods and query syntax of linq... Some of my co-workers are SQLers, so they prefer the query syntax and so if my project involves them, I tend to stick with that way of writing my Linq... As for your reply, it seems, then, that the way I wrote the code should do it as efficiently as possible, no? Since I only hit the DB as is necessary, right??

Comment: Besides the `Distinct`, which would be a data modeling issue more than anything, I think your code is fine.  You select only the data you need and you are materializing the data when you need them opposed to it being a side-effect when accessing the data (like having data-binding do it).  The next biggest thing would be to use the `Include` statement if you want to eagerly load child collections.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!! - For cases when I have linked datasets, I do use the `Include`... That makes me feel **MUCH** better that I'm not doing something wrong... Now to loo a bit more closely on optimizing the SQL Server tables... Truly, thank you!!!!

Comment: FYI - I just accepted your solution, but can't award the bounty for 21 more hours... I will as soon as I can... THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP!!!